# Android tracedmdump post_trace: command not found malformed trace

Tags: android, macos, performance, emulation, trace

I am attempting to use tracedmdump to parse trace files off the Android emulator. I have gone backwards and forwards with the Android OS repo, building the kernel, etc, and I can only assume I missed a step since when I run tracedmdump I get the output:

```
-bash: post_trace: command not found
***
*** Error: malformed trace.  Did you remember to exit the emulator?
***
```

I'm getting my trace files through:

```
$ android create avd -n <emu name> -t <target id> -p <my dir> -s <skin> -b armabi-v7a -c 256M -f
$ emulator -trace <folder name> -avd <avd name> -memory 2048 -gpu on -debug-init
```

then once the emulator is going I use F9 to start then stop tracing.

I've looked, and there's no sign of post_trace anywhere on my machine. I have found 0 resources for why this might be, so I'm lead to believe that something quietly failed in my build process, but I have no idea what it could possibly be. I'm on Mac OSX, and attempting to use the manta kernel, but I don't know what other information could be useful. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `cd` `into /sdk/emulator/qtools` folder, and type `mm` command option to compile those tools.